# Android Sensor List View

Tags: android, list, listview, sensors

i am a novice on android developpement and i need to view a list of sensors on may android 3.1 device.

I have this code:

```
package milos.exemplesensorlist;

import java.util.List;


import milos.exemplesensorlist.R;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ExempleSensorListActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //get all sensors
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    final List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    sensorListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sensor_listview);   //ERROR
    sensorListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { //ERROR
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, //ERROR
                long arg3) {
            showSensorInfo(sensors.get(position).getType());
        }
    });



    //set an empty adapter for ListView
    ArrayAdapter<String> sensorNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


    for (Sensor s : sensors) {
        sensorNames.add(s.getName());
        Log.i("sensor", s.getName());
    }
    sensorListView.setAdapter(sensorNames);  //ERROR
}
```

}

It seems to work for te android developpers who write this but i can't make it working on my device (see: "//ERROR").
I think that i need the right .xml code and some declarations on the .java code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Post the XML layout and also the logcat output

Comment: Here is the xml file:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>

it is the original xml.

What is the logcat output?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Is this question up to date?

If yes. Here are some hints for you:

1. XML-Layout is not consistent with the stuff you are requesting in your ExempleSensorListActivity. E.g. the XML-File doesn't have any id named "sensor_listview".
2. After "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" you should call straight "setContentView(R.layout.main);". The rest after that to initial calls.
3. Your "sensorListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sensor_listview);" should be written as: "ListView sensorListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sensor_listview);"
4. You can find almost everywhere an idea about requesting an sensor list (e.g. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-identify)
5. You should familiarize yourself with ListViews and add the sensor list to your ArrayAdapter.
6. Here an example:

public class SensorikTestActivity extends Activity {

```
private ListView listView;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private List<Sensor> deviceSensors = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listView = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1));

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sensor>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceSensors));
}
```

}

If you want to have the names of the sensors you have to put all your sensors in a new list and with only the names or you have to overwrite the toString() method of your List.

Hope it helps a bit.

Volker